# return class hibernate with parameters string and bigdecimal

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, list, return

How can return correctly this query with hibernate?

Help me please

```
    @Override
    public UsuarioValido validarUserLoggin(String loggin, BigDecimal canal) throws Exception{
        Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT A.ID_USER, '' AS nombre_canal_canales, A.CANAL_ID, '' AS nombre_pto_vta_puntos_de_venta, "
                + " A.PUNTO_VTA_ID, A.LOGGIN, A.PASSWORD, A.NOMBRES, A.APELLIDOS, A.SN_CAMBIO_PASS, A.ULTINGRESO, A.ULTCMBCONT, A.ESTADO, A.CONTINTENTOS, "
                + " B.NU_INT_PER AS NRO_INT_PASS,  A.EMAIL, B.NDIASINACT AS DIAS_VENC_CLAV "
                + " FROM "+General.Esquema_DB+".SEG_USER A "
                + " LEFT JOIN "+General.Esquema_DB+".SEGPOLSEG B ON A.ID_USER = B.ID "
                + " WHERE A.LOGGIN = '"+loggin+"' AND A.CANAL_ID = "+canal);
        List rs = q.list();

         List<UsuarioValido> validos = q.list();
        for (UsuarioValido usuarioValido : validos) {
          System.out.println(usuarioValido.toString());
         }

        UsuarioValido max = (UsuarioValido)rs.get(0);
        return max;


    }
```

Comment: what is not working? what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it here:

```
 List<UsuarioValido> rs = q.list();
```

I think this is the best way to do it and not error prone. But do make sure that the query you are using sends back only that class and not a field of that class or results obtained from `count()`, `avg()` etc.

But since you are fetching fields you won't be able to use that.

In Hibernate it is recommended to bring back the results in form of List of particular classes and not use `Select ...`